# asp.net core and angular 5 modular application

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, angular5, modular-design

I'm working on a big project. I'm using `asp.net core 2`, `web api` and `angular 5` (spa).
The project is somewhat modular but not in front-end part.
What I need is that: There is a container that is main page and include some basics like nav-menu and etc.
whenever I put my extension dll(another core project) in sub folder it will load with all things including angular modules.
For instance I have a project, include Contact Module, core project has no dependency on it. Contact Module will load its `apis` and its `UI` as well(add some menu in nav-menu, sub menu and etc).
There might be a way that I'll be able to inject Angular module from another project to main project.
Current folder structure is like this:

[image]

I'm looking for best solution, Any ideas are welcome and thanks in advance.